# Using proximity sensor with onSensorChanged

Tags: android, proximity, proximitysensor

I'm using the proximity sensor to increase a number in a `TextView`, it work's but it's triggered in increments of two ie `0 2 4 6 8`. I would like to get increments of one, is it possible?

```
TextView text ;
SensorManager sm ;
Sensor Proxsens;
int i=0 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_id);
    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Proxsens = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

    sm.registerListener(this,Proxsens,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    i++;
//  text.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

Comment: there's no "solution", it's doing that because `onSensorChanged` is called two times in a row because the system computed 2 changes in a row. You can double check this behaviour but putting a `Log.d(...` line inside the callback. If you still want the `TextView` to change slower, there are several different techniques of debounce that could be used. Google it.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if (event.values[0] == 0) {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```